# Alertify height to bigger the window

Tags: jquery, css, alertify

I am using Alertify. I have followed [these](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) instruction on how to set it up.

My problem is that the confirm dialog is bigger than the window. it is hard to reproduce this problem so I have uploaded a image. When I look at computed styles the height is at 100% and 933.33px. The problem might be that I have other styles interfering with the alertify css. Any ideas on how I can solve this? (When I add height:180px; to `.alertify` the confirm dialog is resized properly. But this feels like a not so good Idea.
Here is my codesnippet:

```
 jQuery(".erase").on('click', function (index, value) {
       alertify.confirm("Vill du radera denna tid?", function (e) {
                        if (e) {
                            alertify.success("Tiden är raderad!");
                        } else {
                            alertify.error("Tiden raderades inte!");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: do you want to change the height?

Comment: Yes. but shouldt the hieght already be set to a nice amount?

Comment: Provide your code / snippet

Comment: You can also pass a percent of the document clientWidth/clientHeight

Comment: provided the snippet¨

Comment: Wierd thing. In Edge and firefox the Alertify confirm has the proper height from the start. Tested on My Iphone 7 Plus and the height is ok there to. Maybe there is something with the chrome on my computre. Old data